# How to replace all non-alphabetic characters and keep the spaces?

Tags: java

I am trying to replace all characters that are not letters in a string, but keep the spaces between words.

The code I have so far:

```
String newWords = words.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");
```

I also tried this one:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]
```

The problem with the code is that it removes everything but the numbers in the string.

Comment: I tried using this text: "Mercury is the smallest and innermost planet in the Solar System. Its orbit around the Sun takes 87.97 days, the shortest of all the planets in the Solar System. It is named after the Roman deity Mercury, the messenger of the gods."

Comment: It deletes the dot between the 87.97, but wont remove the numbers itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *It deletes the dot between the 87.97, but wont remove the numbers itself*

`[^...]` means [*every character except*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). So `[^A-Za-z0-9 ]` means: match (and replace/remove) everything *except* `A-Z` `a-z` `0-9`  and `space`. In other words those characters are *protected* from removal.

If you also want to remove numbers (series of digits) remove `0-9` from your regex.

```
String newWords = words.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]", "");
```